# Highlight mysterious behaviour in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have set a custom list selector for a Simple `ListView` but when I select an item, the whole `ListView` turns blue. I don't understand where the problem is.

This is my ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/TopListView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/regular_selector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

and it's the regular_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

Comment: so you got the soln? if not can you tell what is your expected result?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue of the whole list view highlighting, when using a color as the background. Curiously this only happened below api 11.

Solution was to use a solid shape drawable to wrap the colour:

list_selector_shaped_background_press.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/list_selector_pressed"/>
</shape>
```

List_selector_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />

    <!-- this has to be in a shaped drawable otherwise the whole list is highlighted selects -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_shaped_background_pressed" />

        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_shaped_background_pressed" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I had been searching for a solution since a couple of weeks now. This really helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the usual problem. You have to set this in your listview:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

The goal is to disable an optimization that the framework does for improving drawing performance during scrolling operations.

Answer (score 0):

When I set the regular_selector.xml as listview item background it work!